# dbtCloud API environment_id

Tags: dbt

I am working to use the dbtCloud V2.0 API and want to create a job.  However I am unclear on what the environment_id is or how to use it.  Could someone explain this to me or point me to additional documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to your environment in the dbt Cloud interface, your environment id will be in the url, eg

```
https://cloud.getdbt.com/#/accounts/11111/projects/22222/environments/33333/
```

Your environment id is `33333`